# How to keep the design window from automatically popping up in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time I open up an aspx page it splits my screen between the source and design screens.  I can change it over manually each time but it's starting to drive me nuts.  Is there a way to make it only open the source window by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on any .aspx file in the Solution Explorer, and choose "Open With...".  In there, you can choose "Source Code (Text) Editor", then hit "Set as Default".

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options (Its there somewhere) I managed to change so when I open vb.net forms that the code view opens rather than the designer.