# Visual Studio Unit Test Sessions window automatically popping up whenever I open my solution

Tags: visual-studio

And I don't want it to. What gives? Is there a setting to disable this thing? Basically, I accidentally ran the built-in test runner instead of my preferred (resharper/ncrunch/etc.) test runner, and now this blasted window pops up every time!

Note: Not the same problem as this question: [How to keep the design window from automatically popping up in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671351/how-to-keep-the-design-window-from-automatically-popping-up-in-visual-studio-201)

Comment: See: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104318--Unit-Test-Sessions-window-is-always-shown-on-Visual-Studio-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stifle the Unit Test Sessions window, you have to close all the sub-tabs inside the window. Closing the last tab will also close the main window and it will stay closed when opening the solution next. Problem solved.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention: Marking this as the accepted as it answers the non-resharper issue that I'm asking about. But the other answer is helpful, so by all means, continue with the upvoting on it.

Answer (score 9):

If 'Unit Test Sessions' window is always opened on Visual Studio start and you'd like it not to happen, please uncheck the 'Save and restore Unit Test Sessions' checkbox located in the "ReSharper | Options | Tools | Unit Testing" dialog.

Comment: Does this affect Resharper's unit test thing, or the built-in VS one?

Comment: It affects ReSharper one.

Comment: Good to know. My problem was with the built-in VS piece, but I do have Resharper as well (as everyone should).